# SourceTree Ignore Pull after master reset (Hard)

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have reset my master to a certain commit (hard) in the sourceTree. The master has been reset but I still get the a message to pull (4 behind). On pull all the previous unwanted changes has been added to my repo. How can I ignore any pull requests after Hard rest?

Answer (score 0):

This is because those changes are on your remote. A hard reset will just discard the changes in your local branch *and* in your working copy.

To fix this you'd either have to do a force push, but this isn't recommended as it's dangerous and pisses off other devs working on that repo, and is generally dangerous. Your other option is going to be resetting the changes to a particular commit. This would look something like this:

```
git reset -q <SHA> -- <filename>

git checkout <SHA> -- <filename>
```

Where  is the commit which you'd want to revet to, and  is the file.

You can do this in SourceTree by context-clicking on a file at a specific commit and hitting "Reset to commit".

Hope that helps.